# How to query data in Oracle, showing 1 extra row under som condition?

Tags: oracle11g

i have a simple table like below,

```
 NAME  MONEY  TYPE        
 ----- ------ ----------  
 Tom   10000  food        
 Jim   6000   food        
 Tom   5000   transport   
 Jim   3000   transport
```

i need to split out one extra row for food , and the money will be 20%*orginal amount, type will be food_split, just like below.

```
 NAME  MONEY  TYPE         
 ----- ------ -----------  
 Tom   8000   food         
 Tom   2000   food_split   
 Tom   5000   transport    
 Jim   4800   food         
 Jim   1200   food_split   
 Jim   3000   transport
```

How should i do it ? Is there any function/solution that can help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key? And which version of Oracle - 11gR1 or 11gR2?

Comment: originally, tom's money food is 10000, i need to split it into 2 rows, one is 10000*20% =2000, the other is 10000-2000=8000.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the table twice, the first time adjusting the food amount to 80% of its original value, and the second just calculating the split values:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (name, money, type) as (
  select 'Tom', 10000,'food' from dual
  union all select 'Jim', 6000, 'food' from dual       
  union all select 'Tom', 5000, 'transport' from dual
  union all select 'Jim', 3000, 'transport' from dual
)
-- actual query
select name,
  money * case when type = 'food' then 0.8 else 1 end as money,
  type
from your_table
union all
select name,
  money * 0.2,
  'food_split'
from your_table
where type = 'food';

NAME            MONEY TYPE      
---------- ---------- ----------
Tom              8000 food      
Jim              4800 food      
Tom              5000 transport 
Jim              3000 transport 
Tom              2000 food_split
Jim              1200 food_split
```

Or if you don't want to hit the table twice you could use a recursive CTE (11gR2+):

```
with rcte (name, money, type) as (
  select name,
    money * case when type = 'food' then 0.8 else 1 end as money,
    type
  from your_table
  union all
  select name,
    money / 4,
    'food_split'
  from rcte
  where type = 'food'
)
select * from rcte;

NAME            MONEY TYPE      
---------- ---------- ----------
Tom              8000 food      
Jim              4800 food      
Tom              5000 transport 
Jim              3000 transport 
Tom              2000 food_split
Jim              1200 food_split
```